# JaVers missing table

Tags: java, javers

In the documentation http://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/#connection-provider it is listed that there should be 4 tables which are jv_cdo_class, jv_global_id, jv_commit, jv_snapshot.

For some reason I don't have the jv_cdo_class and have got a jv_commit_property instead in the public schema.

Is the documentation not up-to-date with the latest release or else the missing table should be in another schema? If this case, where is it pls because I can't find it?

Comment: updated, jv_cdo_class table is removed in 2.0.0 and jv_commit_property is added

Comment: Thanks for your time